# Testing iOS 'Deep Linking' without an App Store ID

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, deep-linking, app-id

So, I have searched for an answer to this, but can't really find anything....

I want to test Facebook deep linking into my iOS app. I want to try passing JSON in the "data" parameter of the request, as such

```
 NSMutableDictionary* defaultParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          JSONString, @"data",                       
                                          @"Check out my app",  @"message",
                                          nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
           andParams:defaultParams
         andDelegate:nil];
```

In order for this to show up as a notification to the receiving user (on mobile), I must have either a mobile website URL or, deep linking and an App Store ID entered in the Facebook App settings page. This took me ages to work out but I've got this far...

Now if I put in the App Store ID of one of my existing published apps, this works, but redirects to the wrong application (or iTunes/AppStore if it's not installed).

I really want to test how *my* application will handle being woken by my corresponding Facebook app, without submitting it to the App Store.

Does anyone have a workaround or a way to achieve this? Can I just make an app in iTunes connect and not submit it? How will Facebook/my device know the two are connected if it's not live?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup your app in iTunes Connect.  Make sure you go all the way to the point where it says Ready to Upload Binary.  If you then view details of your app in iTunes Connect it will give you your iTunes id.  You can use that with Facebook.